# SwiftUi overlay view stops animating

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a camera built in swift and I want to allow the user to focus the camera on a certain spot. When the user clicks anywhere on the screen I want to display an animating view that represents a focus action. This view functions correctly but after clicking on multiple different spots on the screen then the view stops animating and freezes above the camera. I tried using dispatch queues so the view always goes away after the delay but this didn't work.

```
struct HomeStory: View {
    @State var focusLocation: (CGFloat, CGFloat)?
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            CameraStoryView()
                .onTapGesture { tapP in
                    UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light).impactOccurred()
                    focusLocation = (tapP.x, tapP.y)
                    cameraModel.focus(at: CGPoint(x: tapP.x, y: tapP.y))
                }

            let w = widthOrHeight(width: true)
            let h = widthOrHeight(width: false)
            if let points = focusLocation, (points.0 > 20) && (points.0 < w - 20) && (points.1 > 80) && (points.1 < h - (h * 0.3)) {
                FocusView()
                    .position(x: points.0, y: points.1 - 35)
                    .onAppear {
                        let p1 = points.0
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.75) {
                            if (focusLocation?.0 ?? 0.0) == p1 {
                                focusLocation = nil
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .offset(y: 35)
            }
     }
}
struct FocusView: View {
    @State var animate = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(.white.opacity(0.75))
                .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                .scaleEffect(self.animate ? 1 : 0)
                .opacity(animate ? 0 : 1)
            
            Circle()
                .fill(.white)
                .frame(width: 7, height: 4)
                .scaleEffect(self.animate ? 7.0 : 1)
                .opacity(animate ? 0.3 : 1)
        }
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.animate = true
            }
        }
        .onDisappear {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.animate = false
            }
        }
        .animation(.linear(duration: 0.7), value: animate)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onAppear in your `HomeStory` View may not fire if a new location is set before the `focusLocation` is set to nil. Your animation will also not start from the beginning (it is the same FocusView and its animate state is already set to true).

Assuming you only want to display one FocusView at a time, you can use an `.id` view modifier coupled to the location. This will make sure your animation resets for every new location. Something like this:

```
struct FocusLocation {
    let x: CGFloat
    let y: CGFloat
    
    // create unique id for every new location
    let id = UUID()
}

struct HomeStory: View {
    @State var focusLocation: FocusLocation?
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            Color.blue
                .onTapGesture { tapP in
                    // new location with a new id
                    focusLocation = FocusLocation(x: tapP.x, y: tapP.y)
                }
            
            if let focusLocation {
                FocusView()
                    .position(x: focusLocation.x, y: focusLocation.y)
                    .task {
                        do {
                            try await Task.sleep(for: .milliseconds(750))
                            self.focusLocation = nil
                        } catch {
                            // the task is cancelled
                            // (the view has been replaced)
                        }
                    }
                    // new id means a new View
                    .id(focusLocation.id)
            }
        }
    }
}
    
struct FocusView: View {
    @State var animate = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(.white.opacity(0.75))
                .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                .scaleEffect(self.animate ? 1 : 0)
                .opacity(animate ? 0 : 1)
            
            Circle()
                .fill(.white)
                .frame(width: 7, height: 4)
                .scaleEffect(self.animate ? 7.0 : 1)
                .opacity(animate ? 0.3 : 1)
        }
        .onAppear { animate = true }
        .animation(.linear(duration: 0.7), value: animate)
    }
}
```